# Printing out a triangle using stars

Tags: c, geometry

I am trying to print out an equilateral triangle using only repetition statements, however I can't seem to get it to work the way I want. Below is my code and the output it gives after I run the program.

```
int main(void)
{
int i, iR;

for (iR=0; iR<7; iR++) {
    for (i=0; i<iR; i++) {
        printf(" ");
    }
    for (i=0; i<(2*iR-1); i++) {
        printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;

 *
  ***
   *****
    *******
     *********
      ***********
```

Comment: Looks like a triangle to me. What's the problem?

Comment: What have you tried to fix it? You can see that the number of stars is correct, and the number of spaces is wrong. Figure out how that number is wrong and what calculation you need to do to make it right. Do it by hand once, and make a table of row-vs-#spaces if you can't figure it out outright.

Comment: @MarkRansom Its an obtuse triangle, perhaps OP wants an isosceles or equilateral ;)

Comment: Got a feeling of deja-vous!

Answer (score 2):

You are printing more spaces as it get close to the base, instead of doing the opposite. You have to invert this logic.

Instead of using `for (i=0; i<iR; i++)`, try `for (i=0; i<(7-iR); i++)`.

http://ideone.com/riHzxN